# Script to download emails from Exchange as HTML, Can't use outlook

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I have a script already that can download email attachments using EWS to avoid having outlook installed/opened.
I'm now wanting to save email content, preferably as a HTML file, but otherwise as .eml or .msg.

My other thread about the attachments is here: [Download attachments with multiple subjects from Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439222/download-attachments-with-multiple-subjects-from-exchange)

I was hoping that the existing script could be adapted somehow, but honestly I have no idea.

```
$MailboxName = "me@mymail.com"
$Subjects = @(
          'Subject1',
          'Subject2'
        )

[regex]$SubjectRegex = ‘^(?i)(‘ + (($Subjects |foreach {[regex]::escape($_)}) –join “|”) + ‘)$’

$downloadDirectory = "C:\temp"


Function FindTargetFolder($FolderPath){
$tfTargetidRoot = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::MsgFolderRoot,$MailboxName)
$tfTargetFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$tfTargetidRoot)

for ($lint = 1; $lint -lt $pfArray.Length; $lint++) {
    $pfArray[$lint]
    $fvFolderView = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(1)
    $SfSearchFilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+isEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderSchema]::DisplayName,$pfArray[$lint])
            $findFolderResults = $service.FindFolders($tfTargetFolder.Id,$SfSearchFilter,$fvFolderView)
    if ($findFolderResults.TotalCount -gt 0){
        foreach($folder in $findFolderResults.Folders){
            $tfTargetFolder = $folder               
        }
    }
    else{
        "Error Folder Not Found"
        $tfTargetFolder = $null
        break
    }   
}
$Global:findFolder = $tfTargetFolder
}

$dllpath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.0\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dllpath)
$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2007_SP1)


$windowsIdentity = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$sidbind = "LDAP://<SID=" + $windowsIdentity.user.Value.ToString() + ">"
$aceuser = [ADSI]$sidbind

$uri=[system.URI] "https://webmail.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"
$service.Url = $uri

FindTargetFolder($ProcessedFolderPath)

$folderid = new-object  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,$MailboxName)
$InboxFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)
$Sfsub = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::Subject,$Subject[0])
$sfCollection = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+SearchFilterCollection([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.LogicalOperator]::And);
$sfCollection.add($Sfsub)
$sfCollection.add($Sfha)
$view = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(2000)
$frFolderResult = $InboxFolder.FindItems($sfCollection,$view)

foreach ($miMailItems in $frFolderResult.Items)
 {
$miMailItems.body.text | set-content C:\temp
 }
```

Comment: Are you wanting to save the entire email (including all in the message headers), or just the body?

Comment: Just the body of the email will do. Preserving formatting doesn't matter, other than line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Using the foreach loop from your other script:

```
foreach ($miMailItems in $frFolderResult.Items)
 {
  $miMailItems.body.text | set-content <filepath>
 }
```

You'll need to come up with a file naming scheme for the output files, but getting the email body text out to a file is relatively trivial.

Comment: Thanks! Where exactly do I put this? In place of what I currently have from the first "foreach" or the second one?  or both?

Comment: That should replace both of them.  You have nested foreach loops in the other script because each email could have multiple attachments.  Here you only need one, because there will only be one body.

Comment: I've added the script above into the original post, Getting the following errors when i run the script:
50 char:147 Cannot index into a null array.
52 char:18 Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
54 char:41 Exception calling "FindItems" with "2" argument(s): "The request failed schema validation: The element 'And' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2
006/types' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'SearchExpression' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'."

Comment: I think that's being caused by $Sfha being null.

Comment: Removing the line with $Sfha doesn't really achieve a whole lot. I still get the other two errors and no email body downloaded.

Comment: I don't have an Exchange server to run it against right now, and it's late.  I'll have a look at it tomorrow if you haven't figure it out by then.

Comment: I still haven't been able to get this working.. any advice @mjolinor ?